# how to make the margin constant on both side of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make a browser independent code with a search bar in it ( this search bar i took  from demos.jQuery.com) but now when I am trying to fix the margin percent in the left and right side ( i want it center aligned even when browser width is changed )  I am unable to do that , I am new to CSS can someone help ?

the code that i made till now is :

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><p class="p1"><b>Composite<img class="img1" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/arrow_sans_down-128.png" alt="alternate"></b></p></div>

<div id=""main>
 <div data-role="main" id="main" class="ui-content">
    <form>
      <input data-type="search" id="divOfPs-input">
    </form>
    <div class="elements" data-filter="true" data-input="#divOfPs-input">
      <p><strong>These</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
      <p><strong>p elements</strong> nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
      <p><strong>are</strong> et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est</p>
      <p><strong>filterable</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#header
{   position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#D1D3D4;
    verticle-align="middle";
    left:0;

}
.img1
{
    position:relative;
    height:13px;
    float:right;
    padding-right:12%;
}

.p1{

    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:5%;
    padding-left:7%;
    width:100%;

}

#main
{   
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:80px;
    left:-.3%;
    margin-right:2%;
    width:98%;
    border-right:5%;

}
```

[Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/3je1bk67/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you have defined `98%` width without `box-sizing: border-box;` so padding was pushing content outside of visible area. You have to adjust `#main` div to:

```
#main
{   
    /* left:-.3%;
    margin-right:2%; */
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3je1bk67/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your elements centred using `margin-right` and `margin-left` try this:

```
/* just change the element tag you want to center */
p{ 
  margin-left:10%;
  margin-right:10%;
}
```

That will make all your `<p>` elements centred, and you can apply it to any element.

Take a look at **[this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3je1bk67/5/)**.

Answer (score 1):

to allign search bar in the middle you just have to add this

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

[image]
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help you:
[How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

*Also you have a typo in your code: `<div id=""main>` instead of `<div id="main">`.*

Answer (score 0):

### Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3je1bk67/6/

you can resize the browser to see the effect

```
  #main
    {   
        margin:30px 0px 0px 0px;

    }
```